# How to get Value From Key Like this "First-Name" from JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have JSON Object like this and I want to get the value of Key "First-Name" and "Last-Name"

```
data={ 
{ 
"objects":[ 
{ 
"ID":"1",
"Country":"Sudan",
"First-Name":"Noemi",
"Last-Name":"Harris"
},
{ 
"ID":"2",
"Country":"Honduras",
"First-Name":"Carol",
"Last-Name":"Mould"
},
{ 
"ID":"3",
"Country":"Togo",
"First-Name":"Dakota",
"Last-Name":"Tindall"
},
{ 
"ID":"4",
"Country":"Lebanon",
"First-Name":"Penelope",
"Last-Name":"Donovan"
},
{ 
"ID":"5",
"Country":"Bahrain",
"First-Name":"Rufus",
"Last-Name":"Baker"
}
]}
```

I have tried this JQuery but couldn't get value

```
$each(data.objects,function(index,value){
console.log(value.First-Name);
```

})
Please help me for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery` detects `.First-Name` as `.First` only i.e. it doesn't accept `-key` of the form `name-key`. So what you have to do is `['First-Name']`

```js
data={ 
"objects":[ 
{ 
"ID":"1",
"Country":"Sudan",
"Frist-Name":"Noemi",
"Last-Name":"Harris"
},
{ 
"ID":"2",
"Country":"Honduras",
"Frist-Name":"Carol",
"Last-Name":"Mould"
},
{ 
"ID":"3",
"Country":"Togo",
"Frist-Name":"Dakota",
"Last-Name":"Tindall"
},
{ 
"ID":"4",
"Country":"Lebanon",
"Frist-Name":"Penelope",
"Last-Name":"Donovan"
},
{ 
"ID":"5",
"Country":"Bahrain",
"Frist-Name":"Rufus",
"Last-Name":"Baker"
}
]}

   $.each(data.objects,function(index,value){
     console.log("First name: "+value['Frist-Name']);
     console.log("Last name: "+value['Last-Name']);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use square bracket notation like so:

```js
const data = {
  "objects": [{
      "ID": "1",
      "Country": "Sudan",
      "First-Name": "Noemi",
      "Last-Name": "Harris"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "Country": "Honduras",
      "First-Name": "Carol",
      "Last-Name": "Mould"
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "Country": "Togo",
      "First-Name": "Dakota",
      "Last-Name": "Tindall"
    },
    {
      "ID": "4",
      "Country": "Lebanon",
      "First-Name": "Penelope",
      "Last-Name": "Donovan"
    },
    {
      "ID": "5",
      "Country": "Bahrain",
      "First-Name": "Rufus",
      "Last-Name": "Baker"
    }
  ]
}

$.each(data.objects, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value["First-Name"]);
    console.log(value["Last-Name"]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

You can also do this with pure JavaScript:

```js
const data = {
  "objects": [{
      "ID": "1",
      "Country": "Sudan",
      "First-Name": "Noemi",
      "Last-Name": "Harris"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "Country": "Honduras",
      "First-Name": "Carol",
      "Last-Name": "Mould"
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "Country": "Togo",
      "First-Name": "Dakota",
      "Last-Name": "Tindall"
    },
    {
      "ID": "4",
      "Country": "Lebanon",
      "First-Name": "Penelope",
      "Last-Name": "Donovan"
    },
    {
      "ID": "5",
      "Country": "Bahrain",
      "First-Name": "Rufus",
      "Last-Name": "Baker"
    }
  ]
}

data.objects.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value["First-Name"]);
    console.log(value["Last-Name"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this, foreach part maybe not correct.

```
var j_data = JSON.parse(data)
foreach(var item in j_data.objects)
{
console.log(item.First_Name);
}
```

Comment: You have not structured your First_Name correctly, it is First-Name. If you tried First-Name like the post asked in your method, you would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, your object had an extra { at the top. below is the answer.

```
const data={ 
//{
"objects":[ 
{ 
"ID":"1",
"Country":"Sudan",
"First-Name":"Noemi",
"Last-Name":"Harris"
},
{ 
"ID":"2",
"Country":"Honduras",
"First-Name":"Carol",
"Last-Name":"Mould"
}
]};

for(let char in data.objects){
    console.log(data.objects[char]['First-Name']);
    console.log(data.objects[char]['Last-Name']);
}
```